# Migrating Data from Debian to ubuntu server

Tags: debian, kernel

I am current in the process of migrating my website(big and complex with mysql backend) from debian server to ubuntu server. The kernel of debian and ubuntu are different. I have some concerned questions :

1. Is it possible to migrate database and website (with etc and home folder) from one server to another if the kernel version is different?
2. My understanding is it may cause error, because the kernel architecture are different which may cause some dependency error. Does my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Why do you migrate from a stable operating system to one that is derived from the unstable-tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not copy the binary database files. Instead do a dump and restore the dump. That's the most portable way.

Dump:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [databasename] > backupfile.sql
```

Restore:

```
mysql -u [username] -p [password] [database_to_restore] < backupfile.sql
```

More detailled information can be found here: [Backup and Restore MySQL Database Using mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)

The kernel versions don't matter. What matters are the versions of the programs installed on both systems, e.g. MySQL, PHP, etc. Using different version might cause incompatibilities.

Comment: Thank you Marco, is the mysqldump will pull down the database without causing any harm to exist database right. Its like coping and compress it into a single sql file right?

Comment: Correct. Note that the sql file easily gets HUGE. You should consider piping through gzip: `mysqldump … | gzip > backupfile.sql.gz` and `gunzip < backupfile.sql.gz | mysql …`.

Answer (score 1):

mySQL should not be that problematic - see Marco's response.

If you have got a DB-backend you most propably also have a programming language in between - possibly PHP?

You should use a compatible version there and watch its error-logs closely.

Web-server, programming-language and database do not care much about the kernel - they should simply work using the kernel-services.

Main difference in Ubuntu is that is has more beta-kernel-drivers for nifty new devices built in.